# installed windows server 2008 r2 sp1 and only powershell appears

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I installed windows server 2008 r2 sp1 and there is only powershell appears on the screen. I cannot reach to anything else. I thought when I install windows server 2008 r2 sp1 from dvd, it will look like a regular windows edition. should I install something else?

I want to use this server for learning purposes. therefore, I need to install sql server 2012 and other stuff too. So, I need to have all tools

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You most likely selected `Server Core` installation, which will yield the result you described.

During setup, you should be able to select which edition of Windows you want to install. Steer clear of said variant and you will get a "regular" Windows Server installation.

Your license key might dictate which editions are available.

Comment: thanks a lot. we are Microsoft Partner as a company, so I am installing from DVD which never asks a license key. As you said, I might havent paid enough attentin during the installation. thanks a lot